# Select multiple date columns and convert factor variables to date

Tags: r, date, select, multiple-columns, tidyselect

I have a data.frame with multiple columns that contain dates. At present they are recognised as "factor" class. **I want to select all the columns that should be dates (there are 10 of them, they all have "Date" in their name, e.g. Date_Construc, Date_use, Comp_date...) and convert them from factor to date**.

Here's what I've tried:
First I want to select the relevant columns in a vector

```
library(tidyselect)
date_vars <- vars_select(names(df1), contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE))
```

then

```
library(lubridate)
date_vars <- dmy(date_vars)
```

Also tried

```
date_vars <- vars_select(names(df1), contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE))
df1[date_vars] <- lapply(df1[date_vars], as.Date)
```

I get

```
 Error in as.Date.numeric(X[[i]], ...) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Also

```
date_vars <- vars_select(names(df1), contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE))
df1[date_vars] <- dmy(as.character(df1[date_vars])
```

with result,

```
 Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

This is sample data in current format:

```
Date_Construct= c("10/03/2018 00:00", "21/03/2015 00:00", "20/02/2012 00:00")
Date_use = c("02/08/2007 00:00", "31/10/2007 00:00", "13/08/2008 00:00")
ID = c("0001", "34560", "100041531")
Comp = c("Revis", "Succ", "Revis")

dfq= data.frame(`ID`, `Date_Construct`, `Date_use`, `Comp`)



    ID      Date_Construct     Date_use            Comp
1   0001    10/03/2018 00:00    02/08/2007 00:00    Revis
2   34560   21/03/2015 00:00    31/10/2007 00:00    Succ
3   100041531   20/02/2012 00:00    13/08/2008 00:00    Revis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer based on new data provided.

Try the following. There's no need to strip out the time component of the date-time string. You can parse it using the `lubridate` function which matches the data (in this case, `dmy_hm()`) then disregard it.

```
dfq_parsed <- dfq %>%
  mutate(across(contains("date", ignore.case = TRUE), dmy_hm))
```

This yields:

```
         ID Date_Construct   Date_use  Comp
1      0001     2018-03-10 2007-08-02 Revis
2     34560     2015-03-21 2007-10-31  Succ
3 100041531     2012-02-20 2008-08-13 Revis
```

Where the dates are as POSIXct, but that's easy enough to work with:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ID            : chr  "0001" "34560" "100041531"
 $ Date_Construct: POSIXct, format: "2018-03-10" "2015-03-21" "2012-02-20"
 $ Date_use      : POSIXct, format: "2007-08-02" "2007-10-31" "2008-08-13"
 $ Comp          : chr  "Revis" "Succ" "Revis"
```

Comment: I've added some example data, though not sure it helps answer the question. Essentially I want to change all columns that are dates from factor to date. I could do it for all 10 coulmns individually, but wondered if there was a way to do it for all 10 at the same time. I'm not sure what `across` is in your code.

Comment: `across` is recent addition to `dplyr` which will do what you're looking for: it will apply dmy() across all variables which contain "Date" (ignoring case).

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately that code doesn't work. The class of the date columns is still factor. I get 20 warnings in the form ```1: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
i Input `..1` is `across(contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE), dmy)`.
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.```

Comment: You'll need to supply some reproducible data. The error is indicating that lubridate can't parse the string as a date: let's look more carefully at how your data are structured.

Comment: Okay, I've added some reproducible data. Is the problem that my dates all have a time (midnight)? I'm trying to remove all the "00:00" with the following, based on your advice above, but also having trouble with this `dfq2= dfq%>%
  mutate(across(contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE), str_remove_all "[00:00]")))`

Comment: Thanks. That's done it. As an aside, can you tell what's wrong with the code I've used to try and remove the time string `dfq2= dfq%>%
  mutate(across(contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE), str_remove_all (" 00:00")))`

Comment: Glad it worked. When using `across` in `mutate`, you pass arguments to the function as another argument, rather than in parentheses, like this: `dfq %>% mutate(across(contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE), str_remove_all, " 00:00")))`